# Convolution in time vs multiplication in frequency

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, convolution

I'm trying to obtain the power in a certain band, but I want to do this in the time domain and not in the frequency domain. The problem - the bands are very tight and therefore using simple filters create overlapping "tails".

Let [a1 a2]Hz is the band I would like to calculate the power for. I can imagine I'm multiplying the frequency domain by a rectangle signal, and therefore I can get it's ifft in time so I may do a convolution in time.

The code is: (matlab)
for x - the signal in time, X=fft(x), W - the window in frequency, w=ifft(W)

```
filteredX=X.*W;
Fx=ifft(filteredX);
Fx2=conv(x,w,'same');
```

The results of the signals are different.
While the filteredX shows the correct spectrum, the fft of Fx2 (the results of the convolution) is completely different.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

As suggested by EitanT (thanks), I've played around with the following code:

```
im = fix(255 * rand(500,1)); 
mask = ones(4,1) / 16; 

% # Circular convolution
resConv = conv(im, mask);

% # Discrete Fourier transform
M = size(im, 1) + size(mask, 1);
resIFFT = ifft(fft(im, M) .* fft(mask, M));
% # Not needed any more - resIFFT = resIFFT(1:end-1);  % # Adjust dimensions

% # Check the difference
max(abs(resConv(:) - resIFFT(:)))
```

Which works fine, but I can't use it so I had to change the parts that are concerned with size issues and got the following (please see comments):

```
 im = fix(255 * rand(500,1)); 
mask = ones(4,1) / 16; 

% # Circular convolution
resConv = conv(im, mask,'same'); % # instead of conv(im, mask)

% # Discrete Fourier transform
M = size(im, 1) % # Instead of: M = size(im, 1) + size(mask, 1);
resIFFT = ifft(fft(im, M) .* fft(mask, M));
resIFFT = resIFFT(1:end-1);  % # Adjust dimensions

% # Check the difference
max(abs(resConv(:) - resIFFT(:)))
```

If though I would expect to get the same results, now the difference is much higher.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify the convolution theorem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025967/verify-the-convolution-theorem). Just use `fft` and `conv` instead of `fft2` and `conv2`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you Eitan. After playing a bit with the referenced code it seems that the problem is with size. I've got a 1XN frequency rectangle (W) and a 1XN frequency spectrum (X). The ifft of w and the signal x are N points long each and the convolution in (N+N+1) long. Taking the options 'same' in the convolution does extracts the  needed N points, but the result in frequency is not identical to the multiplication. Not even close

Comment: By default, the `conv` function filters in the forward direction, so the "extra" time points are being added to the end of the original samples. See my answer below for a more detailed breakdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eitan's earlier [verification of the convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025967/verify-the-convolution-theorem) theorem is excellent. Here, I wanted to demonstrate time-domain convolution for filtering a particular frequency band, and show it is equivalent to frequency-domain multiplication.

Beyond knowing how to run the `fft` and `ifft` function, there are two pieces required in making this work:

1. determining the frequency (Hz) of each Fourier component returned by the `fft` function
2. padding the signal before `fft`, and cropping it after `ifft` or after `conv` function.

The code below generates a random signal, performs both time-domain and freq-domain filtering, and shows the equivalence in a figure something like this:

[image]

```
Nsamp = 50;  %number of samples from signal X
X = randn(Nsamp,1);  %random Gaussian signal
fs = 1000;     %sampling frequency

NFFT = 2*Nsamp;  %number of samples to be used in fft (this will lead to padding)

bandlow = 250;  %lower end of filter band (just an example range)
bandhigh = 450; %upper end of filter band

%construct a frequency axis so we know where Fourier components are

if mod(NFFT,2) == 0 %if there is an even number of points in the FFT
    iNyq = NFFT/2;     %index to the highest frequency
    posfqs = fs*(0:iNyq)/NFFT;  %positive frequencies
    negfqs = -posfqs(end-1:-1:2);  %negative frequencies

else  %if there is an odd number of point in the FFT
    iNyq = floor(NFFT/2);     %index to the highest frequency
    posfqs = fs*(0:iNyq)/NFFT;  %positive frequencies
    negfqs = -posfqs(end:-1:2);  %negative frequencies
end

fqs = [posfqs'; negfqs'];   %concatenate the positive and negative freqs

fftX = fft(X,NFFT);  % compute the NFFT-point discrete Fourier transform of X
                     % becuse NFFT > Nsamp, X is zero-padded

% construct frequency-space mask for the desired frequency range
W = ones(size(fftX)) .* ( and ( abs(fqs) >=  bandlow, abs(fqs) < bandhigh) );

fftX_filtered = fftX.*W; %multiplication in frequency space
X_mult_filtered = ifft( fftX_filtered, NFFT);  %convert the multiplicatively-filtered signal to time domain

w = ifft(W,NFFT); %convert the filter to the time domain
X_conv_filtered = conv(X, w); %convolve with filter in time domain

%now plot and compare the frequency and time domain results
figure; set(gcf, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.45 0.15 0.4 0.7])

subplot(3,1,1); 
plot(X)
xlabel('Time Samples'); ylabel('Values of X'); title('Original Signal')

subplot(3,1,2); 
plot(X_conv_filtered(1:Nsamp))
xlabel('Time Samples'); ylabel('Values of Filtered X'); title('Filtered by Convolution in Time Domain')

subplot(3,1,3); 
plot(X_mult_filtered(1:Nsamp))
xlabel('Time Samples'); ylabel('Values of Filtered X'); title('Filtered by Multiplication in Frequency Domain')

for sp = 1:3; subplot(3,1,sp); axis([0 Nsamp -3 3]); end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I should take a bit of time to have deeper look into what you've written. But in the meanwhile - thank you!!!

Comment: @HelloWorld, you're welcome. It was an interesting exercise. Another thing to keep in mind is that it is important, when finding the `W` in frequency space, to include both positive and negative frequencies, to ensure that the inverse FFT produces a real-valued function.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an excellent example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUafo2UZowE

EDIT:

Just don't forget the padding. for 1d signals it's like this:

```
lh=length(h);
lx=length(x);

h=[h zeros(1,lx-1)];
x=[x zeros(1,lh-1)];
```

The rest is simple:

```
H=fft(h);
X=fft(x);

Y=H.*X;

y=ifft(Y);

stem(y)
```

If you want to plot the response vs. time:

let's say nh and nx is corresponding times of h and x samples, then the corresponding times of the response samples can be calculated like this:

```
n=min(nh)+min(nx):+max(nh)+max(nx);
```

And finally

```
stem(n,y)
```